# ng-bootstrap tabs not retaining canvas (pdfjs) content

Tags: angular, tabs, angular-ui-bootstrap, pdf.js, ng-bootstrap

Background:

I'm porting an Angular 1 app that uses `UI Bootstrap` to Angular 2 using `ng-bootstrap` (ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.14).  In the Angular 1 app, I use `uib-tabset`, `uib-tab` and `ng-repeat` to dynamically create tabs.  In Angular 2 I'm using `ngb-tabset`, `ngb-tab` and `*ngFor` to do the same.  **Each tab contains a canvas that I populate using pdfjs.** The tab loading works just fine.

But, when I click from away from a tab and back to it, the PDF content is gone.

Thoughts:

The only way I can fix this is by loading the PDF content every time a tab is selected, but I'm not keen on doing that. I notice that in `ng-bootstrap` only the current/visible tab is actually in the DOM. In UI Bootstrap all tabs are in the DOM but of course only one is visible - and navigating between tabs doesn't result in the PDF content disappearing.

Has anyone seen this behavior in the new bootstrap? Sounds like the new bootstrap is not saving all content of a tab when it removes it from the DOM when you click on a different tab. Any thoughts/suggestions as to how I can work around this to achieve the previous behaviour?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-bootstrap: accordion reinitializes component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451452/ng-bootstrap-accordion-reinitializes-component)

Comment: This is a duplicate of the existing question http://stackoverflow.com/q/40451452/1418796 (please note that the mentioned question refers to accordion but the tabset implementation is almost identical to the accordion one so the same rules apply).